# How to achieve "simple" deformation of a plane?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, rigging

Is there a way to achieve exactly (that's crucial) the same corner bend definition of a plane in blender?

[image: bend the corner]

Comment: What sort of material would bend like that in the real world?

Comment: Only unobtainium I think. Is there any other way than sculpting, to achieve this shape?

Comment: what does the shape look like from the side view? I'm curious as to what you will use it for.

Comment: I don't consider side view, only top view for this one. Two things for sure - bend have to be above, and it should be done from one plane. I'm using this to see if round bend edge is doable in blender in easy way.

Comment: maybe high sub-div levels and an IK rig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an armature to deform a sub-divided plane.  Select the plane and <kbd>shift</kbd> select the Armature to make it the primary selection with the plane as the secondary selection.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to parent the plane to the armature.  I selected Armature Deform with Automatic Weights.

[image]

There is a color picker available to select colors from other areas visible in the UI.
If you hover over the color field of a node and press the <kbd>e</kbd> key you can then click on an image that has has been drag 'n dropped into the UV Image Editor.  Now you can pick the various colors of the image to use for the Material and Sky colors.

[image]

You can use Freestyle to add the edge highlighting.

The setup is shown in the following two images.
(i)Activate Freestyle in the Render tab
(ii)Add a Lineset
(iii)Change the color to match.

The color of the paper is multiplied by 3.0 to brighten it up.

[image]

[image]

To get the exact shape of the reference image, you can try a more detailed Armature.

Another option is to add a sphere and use the Snap tool(magnet icon).

Snapping activates when you select one or more vertices and press <kbd>g</kbd> and then <kbd>enter</kbd> to set the movement.

[image]

[image]